# ARMv7-M assembly: unaligned byte replacement in registers?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m

Suppose we have three destination registers, r5, r6, and r7, and consider them to be an array of 12 bytes:

```
r5={a, b, c, d} r6={e, f, g, h} r7={i, j, k, l}
```

What I'd like to do is read eight bytes `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}` from a given memory location, and copy them into the three destination registers to give

```
r5={a, 0, 1, 2} r6={3, 4, 5, 6} r7={7, j, k, l}
```

In other words, I'd like to replace bytes 1-8 of of the array in r5-r7 with the eight bytes read from ROM.

I can do this in six instructions:

```
ldrd    r0, r1, [r3]
bfi     r5, r0, #8, #24
ubfx    r6, r0, #24, #8
bfi     r6, r1, #8, #24
bfc     r7, #0, #8
orr     r7, r7, r1, lsr #24
```

Can it be done in fewer? Assume the absence of floating-point unit.

(Background: this is part of a blitting routine, several pixel patterns are read from memory and composited into a set of registers which is then written to a display buffer with `stmia`.)

Comment: the input and output data structures for lack lf a better term dont match, you cant pre-process the data before writing to the display buffer (as in when you build it in the first place)?

Comment: the pushing/preserving of r5,6,7 is not counted in the cost here? is that buried in the noise somewhere?

Comment: Yes, assume r5-r7 are preserved/restored.

Comment: This is part of a routine that's generating video output on a microcontroller. I don't have enough RAM for a full framebuffer. Instead, I generate one line's worth of pixels every horizontal interrupt.

Comment: there is still code generating those pixels and landing in ram somewhere in a format that is not optimal for the output, then this question related to additional processing of that data.  From a system level can the answer to your question be, do an ldm and an stm to do the bit blit, done.

Comment: if you are on the edge for performance to counting instructions it is time to re-visit the system design

Comment: If not a framebuffer then why is the pixel data in ram in the first place?

Comment: Should have clarified: the pixel data is coming from a table of tiles in ROM. Storing aligned versions of the tiles in RAM is doable and I'll certainly consider it. I'm aware this is all well within the realm of premature optimization though; but this is my first time using Thumb-2 assembly and I'm just trying to get a handle on what's possible. That being said, I have  ~1900 cycles to generate 320 display-ready pixels, so I'm striving to make everything as tight as possible.

Comment: even better, should pre-compute that rom date to make the bitblit smoother

Comment: makes sense to have the rom based data arranged to make it easier on the application, premature optimization or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hesitant to post the following, because it doesn't solve the problem as posed - it assembles the output in memory rather than in the registers.

But for what it's worth:

```
r5,r6,r7 - abcdefghijkl      (as per the question)
r3       - input array ptr   (as per the question)
r2       - output array ptr

                        r5   r6   r7    [r3]         r0    r1        [r2]
                        abcd efgh ijkl  01234567
ldrd    r0, r1, [r3]                                 0123  4567      ------------
str     r5, [r2, #0]                                                 abcd-------- 
str     r7, [r2, #8]                                                 abcd----ijkl 
str.w   r0, [r2, #1]                                                 a0123---ijkl 
str.w   r1, [r2, #5]                                                 a01234567jkl
```

Note that:

- The three output words are assembled in four writes to memory, two of which are unaligned.
- The two `str` instructions are 16-bit encodings.

Comment: hmmm could the OP use an unaligned load for the middle (r6) register...save an instruction...might be an extra clock cycle (might not)...

Comment: Marking your answer correct because it's basically the approach I went with. I took some measurements and it's actually quite a bit cheaper to do unaligned stores than go to great lengths to shuffle things in registers so I can use `strd`/`stm`.

Comment: I would argue it is still worth investigating getting the data in rom at/pre compile time to aid the runtime execution.  no sense the runtime code has to pay for a savings on the pre-compile time code performance.